# how to stretch h1 container to match 100% width of parent div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image: Here is the H1, I want the whitespace to cover 100%]

Here is sample of the code with parent and child as well as the current styling

```css
main #main-content-wrapper div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.overlay1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.overlay3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.jadePackage1:hover .overlay1 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(8, 133, 8, 0.53);
}

.rubyPackage1:hover .overlay2 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(100, 43, 46, 0.53);
}

.sapphirePackage1:hover .overlay3 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.43);
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.jadePackage1 {
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/400/300");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  width: 370px;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  /*border: 1px dotted black;*/
}

ul.colorOptions {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main id="main-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="travelPackages">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 jadePackage1" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; background-color: white;display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: auto; padding: 0 100px 0 100px; ">The Jade Package <span>$19.99</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I am attempting to have the header that reads "The Jade" cover 100% of the top of the photo that way it will look like a header on top of a photo and not one placed in the middle of photo.

I have played around with different display sets and widths yet this is the largest I have been able to get it, close but not quite there.

Comment: In your HTML you have an inline style with `padding: 0 100px 0 100px;`, remove 100px, that causes the problem.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Have you tried removing margins and padding?

Comment: Yes it is Bootstrap formatting for sure. You either have padding on the left and right of the parent Div or margin on the left and right of H1. `p-0` in the Class and `m-0` in the Class will respectively make padding and margin set to zero. Worth noting that  Bootstrap is a CSS framework. Any CSS you add has a chane of screwing you about. I generally find you can edit as many appearance items as you like such as colors, font-sizes, shadows, whatever..... but the moment you begin using CSS to edit the layout of boxes it can get very messy very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit of a mess in inline and css styles, so I suggest you to move all styles to css and reorganize it, then you'll have less troubles when you try to add any new style.

As for your question, `h1` already takes 100% of available width, but it stops because of wrapper's paddings. You need to remove padding in the wrapper container (`.jadePackage1`) and it will work — I added inline `padding: 0` to it. See attached snippet.

```css
main #main-content-wrapper div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.overlay1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.overlay3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.jadePackage1:hover .overlay1 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(8, 133, 8, 0.53);
}

.rubyPackage1:hover .overlay2 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(100, 43, 46, 0.53);
}

.sapphirePackage1:hover .overlay3 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.43);
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.jadePackage1 {
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/400/300");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  width: 370px;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  /*border: 1px dotted black;*/
}

ul.colorOptions {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main id="main-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="travelPackages">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 jadePackage1" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 200px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 0">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; background-color: white;display: flex; justify-content: center; padding: 0 100px 0 100px; ">The Jade Package <span>$19.99</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: awesome!! that fixed the issue immediately. and yeah I know the styling is a mess. I dont plan to keep the inline coding there , just place it when testing for the most part. is that bad practice?

Comment: @lorddupree I can't say it's a bad practice while you test things, but to avoid complication, I'd reduce the number of styles, so when you tested one thing and it works, immediately move that part to CSS before continuing tests with other styles

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always a bad idea to muck around with Bootstrap's grid (containers, rows, and columns). Don't put custom margin and padding on them. Definitely don't use specific widths. That just breaks everything. *Stop using inline styles, even for development.* If you need to experiment, do it in the browser inspector and then put it on a custom class.

I might create a custom class and pull that column's *content* out past the column padding. Leave the grid alone.

```css
.jadePackage1 {
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/400/300");
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 150px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
}

.w-100-in-col {
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-right: -12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main id="main-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="travelPackages">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 jadePackage1">
        <h1 class="w-100-in-col">The Jade Package <span>$19.99</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

My best advice you you right now is to strip out as much of your styling as you can related to Bootstrap elements. Work *with* the library, not against it, and only style your grid *content* unless there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tis rule....

```
.row > .jadePackage1 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

...to reset the default padding applied by bootstrap to the parent container of that h1.

```css
main #main-content-wrapper div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.overlay1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.overlay3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: .1px;
  bottom: 399px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #088508;
}

.jadePackage1:hover .overlay1 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(8, 133, 8, 0.53);
}

.rubyPackage1:hover .overlay2 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(100, 43, 46, 0.53);
}

.sapphirePackage1:hover .overlay3 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.43);
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.jadePackage1 {
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/400/300");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  width: 370px;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  /*border: 1px dotted black;*/
}

ul.colorOptions {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
.row > .jadePackage1 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main id="main-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="travelPackages">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 jadePackage1" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; background-color: white;display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: auto; padding: 0 100px 0 100px;">The Jade Package <span>$19.99</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```